# Postgres database of a cloned project not showing up when I run psql

Tags: django, postgresql

I was under the assumption that Django's models would automatically create the database when I ran migrations, however, I cannot find the database listed in psql despite the fact that the project runs perfectly with all the database info populating the website.

I don't exactly know what to look for in the settings.py file to see where the database is actually being stored but is there any way to find out?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/databases/#creating-your-database

Comment: Create database, put right config in Django settings (with that database name) and run migrate afterwards

Comment: Thank you! Looks like that worked.